# AsyncTask isCancelled() returns true but doInBackground doesn't end

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask which record audio. The problem is once I call `cancel(true)` from the UI thread, `isCancelled()` returns `true` (like it's supposed to) but the `doInBackground` function keeps running and if I run `getStatus()` on the AsyncTask it returns **RUNNING** and neither of the `onCancelled` methods are called nore does `onPostExecute`...

Since all the `doInBackground` code is placed inside `while(!isCancelled())`, the method should end once the task is cancelled...

The while(!isCancelled()) loop ends once I call AsyncTask.cancel(). I think the problem is that `return null` isn't being called and that's why `doInBackground` doesn't end... I may be wrong though...

***code:***

```
package Classes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.appetizers.app.trytabs.Main2Activity;

/**
 * Created by Alon on 09-Aug-16.
 */
public class RecordingTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    AudioRecord record;
    Context context;
    int bufferSize;
    int numSample=0;
    private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100 };
    short[] audioBuffer;

    public RecordingTask2(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("RECTASK", "onPre");
        record = findAudioRecord();
        record.startRecording();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        audioBuffer = new short[bufferSize/2];

        Log.d("RECTASK","before while");
        while(!isCancelled())
        {
            //Log.d("RECTASK","isCancelled = "+isCancelled());
            int numberOfShort = record.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
            numSample +=numberOfShort;
        }
        Log.d("RECTASK", "after while\nisCancelled = "+isCancelled());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        Log.d("RECTASK", "reached onCancel()");
        end();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {
        super.onCancelled(aVoid);
        Log.d("RECTASK", "reached onCancelled(Void)");
        end();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.d("RECTASK", "reached onPost");
        end();
    }

    private void end()
    {
        Log.d("RECTASK","reached end function");
        record.stop();
        record.release();
        ((Main2Activity)context).setNumOfSamples(numSample);
        ((Main2Activity)context).setSamples(audioBuffer);
    }

    public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
        for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
            for (short audioFormat : new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT }) {
                for (short channelConfig : new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO }) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("FINDAUDIO", "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                                + channelConfig);
                        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                        if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                            // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                            AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                            Log.d("FINDAUDIO", "AudioRecorder state = "+recorder.getState());

                            if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                                return recorder;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("FINDAUDIO", rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here's the part of the code in my MainActivity class where I call and cancel the AsyncTask

```
recordSlideBar.setDownRun(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("MAINACT","onDown");
                if(recTask==null || recTask.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                    recTask = new RecordingTask2(Main2Activity.this);
                    recTask.execute();
                }
            }
        });

        recordSlideBar.setUpRun(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("MAINACT", "onUp");
                recTask.cancel(true);
                Log.d("MAINACT", "after cancel\nstatus = "+recTask.getStatus());
                while(recTask.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                {
                    //waiting for task to end...
                }
                ShortBuffer shortBuffer = ShortBuffer.allocate(samples.length);
                playTask = new PlayingTask(Main2Activity.this,shortBuffer,numOfSamples);

            }
        });
```

`recordSlideBar` is a custom view I wrote that has an onTouchListener in it while `recordSlideBar.setDownRun(Runnable)` sets a `Runnable` to the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `recordSlideBar.setUpRun(Runnable)` sets a `Runnable` to the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Basically, I create the AsyncTask and execute it when `ACTION_DOWN` is called and cancel it when `ACTION_UP` is called...

I'm new to the whole audio capturing techniques so you might see some errors in my code regarding that. Please remember that the issue right now is the AsyncTask ;)

**EDIT:** Here's a print-screen of the debugger panel after I cancel the task. notice that the AsyncTask status is **WAIT**, and in the Variables tab, `mCancelled` is `true` and `mStatus` is `Running`

[Screen-shot: asynctask status=wait,cancelled=true,status=running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEjvK.jpg)

Comment: Could you add the code where you start this task and cancel it?

Comment: Anything for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` function could be blocked in

`int numberOfShort = record.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);`

so `while(!isCancelled())` may never got called.

you can put `Log.d()` in the `while` to check if the code is blocked, like

`while(!isCancelled())
        {
            Log.d("RECTASK","start read");
            int numberOfShort = record.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
            numSample +=numberOfShort;
            Log.d("RECTASK","end read");
        }`

Comment: I already had a Log.d inside the while loop and it worked fine (the log appeared again and again until isCancelled() became true and the loop ended).
I erased the log because it made my logcat crash...

Comment: @AlonLevy `Log.d("RECTASK", "after while\nisCancelled = "+isCancelled());`  Is this called after cancel?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question and explained that the while(isCancelled()) loops ends as it should

Comment: @AlonLevy There is something you should know. After you cancel a task, the status of the task will keep being `PENDING` or `RUNNING`. The status won't change after you cancel the task.You should check both status and `isCanceled()`.

Comment: That's good to know! But it doesn't really solve my problem because I do check if the task `isCancelled()` and it returns `true`.
I've added a screen-shot that shows the variables of the task :)

Comment: @AlonLevy Sorry, I was wrong. The status will change to `FINISHED`, but will not change immediately. It will change to `FINISHED` after calling the `onCancelled()` function.  but your `while(recTask.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)` will block the thread, status is still `RUNNING` at that moment, that's why you always got `RUNNING` and `onCancelled` could never be called. You may need to check `status` later or use `isCancelled` instead.

Comment: THANK YOU! I assumed that onCancelled would be called through the AsyncTasks thread so I didn't mind putting that while loop...
Took down the while and onCancelled gets called :)

Comment: @AlonLevy ```ShortBuffer shortBuffer = ShortBuffer.allocate(samples.length);
                playTask = new PlayingTask(Main2Activity.this,shortBuffer,numOfSamples);``` Maybe you could put the code in `end` funtions. No need to use `while` to check status

Comment: No can do... The point is to call `playTask` by users command and not necessarily when the `recordTask` is done.
But I'll figure out something. You've helped enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is stuck because the `AudioRecord.read()` method being used is a blocking call which blocks at the native level rather than the Java level.  So the "interrupt" which is being sent as part of the `AsyncTask.cancel()` will have no effect.  Instead of using this version of `read()`, use the version which takes the `readMode` parameter and set it to `READ_NON_BLOCKING`.  Your loop will then need to deal with partial reads (as well as actually do something with the data - right now it just reads it into a method local array!)

Comment: Tried out your solution. still same problem. isCancelled() becomes true yet doInBackground keeps running.

Comment: If it is set to non-blocking, that should not happen.  While it is running, take a look at the thread stacks and see where the async task thread is at within the `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: I see now that the AsyncTask's status is WAITING yet I don't understand why...
If you'd mind taking a look at the screen-shot I added and give your opinion that'd be great!

Comment: That's actually your main thread waiting for the cancel of the `AsyncTask`.  You'll need to look at the list of all threads for your app's process and find the `AsyncTask` thread (it will be labeled with a name like that) which is running your task.